# Javascript alert when customer fill in the wrong price

Tags: javascript

I have a form (`input type="text" name="amount"`) where the customer need to fill in the total price.
Because the price is for 1 19,95 dollar. When you need 2 it will be 39,90 dollar etc.

So:
1= 19,95, 2= 39,90, 3= 59,85

Is it possible when the customer fill in a wrong price (for example 20,00 instead of 19,95) there will be a javascript alert. If so can somebody help me with the code.

Thanks

Comment: Just calculate final total from code in put it in textbox..... No ERROR..!!!! ;)

Comment: Why must the customer fill in the price instead of your software doing it for them?

Comment: Use a dropdown instead of a `input type=text`. But check the input in javascript/php anyway.

Comment: If there are restricted values, you shouldn't use a text input but a dropdown (or radio buttons, checkboxes, etc. as appropriate in other contexts). A text input says "We accept pretty much anything, as long as you follow the guidelines", which can be "enter a number" or "use only letters and numbers". A dropdown says "we have possibly a lot of values, but they are all here - choose yours".

Comment: It's a long story why it must be done like this.

Comment: It must be a really strange story, too - this seems like it's going against a lot of principles when it comes to forms, also it's rather not user friendly and prone to quirks and just general inconvenience on all sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a **JS Bin** for you:

http://jsbin.com/sidakata/2/

Just a sample, you have to add your complete logic by yourself!

***HTML:***

```
<input id="total" type="text" onkeyup="validateInput();" />
```

***JavaScript:***

```
function validateInput() {
    var total = parseFloat($('#total').val());
    if(!isNaN(total))
      {
        // Add your logic here
        // this is a sample:
        if(total > 19.95)
          {
            alert('Wrong price dude!');
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have many solutions.
one is just check the user input and do a mod.

```
    if (isNaN(x) || (x%19.95) != 0) {
    text = "Input not valid";
    } else {
    text = "Input OK";
    }
```

second,
you can ask the customer quantity, and then internally multiply the unit value and display total price.